# Laravel 8 - How to write statement with paginate instead with get

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use Alias name of column because I have two columns in different tables with the same name, when retrieve them one column will override another column

```
DB::table('trip_user')
        ->join('trips', 'trips.id', '=', 'trip_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->where('guide_id','=',$id)
        ->get(['*','trips.name As tirp_name','trip_user.id As reservation_id'])
```

How can I write it with paginate?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$result = DB::table('trip_user')
        ->join('trips', 'trips.id', '=', 'trip_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->where('guide_id','=',$id)
        ->paginate(100, ['*','trips.name As tirp_name','trip_user.id As reservation_id']);
```

Comment: you´re welcome @HazemAlrfati